# Using SetSourceData

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am a bit of a novice using PowerPoint VBA!

I want to use SetSourceData to change the data range for a chart.

The variables I am using are as follows:

- the relevant active chart is set to the variable Mychart
- the worksheet associated with the chart is set to the variable Myworksheet
- two range variables called LastRow and Last_num_col are set programatically.

All these variables are working just fine in various other lines of code in the VBA routine.

To re-set the range for the chart data I am using the following line of code, but it just does not work and crashes my VBA routine:

```
Mychart.SetSourceData Source:="=Myworksheet.Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(LastRow,Last_num_col))"
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the bot request to add more code so others can better understand my problem, below pls see a basic standalone routine with the problem line concerning "SetSourceData" in context (and you can use this to try it yourself).

Note: the test PowerPoint data file I have used this basic routine on has (i) only 1 slide and (ii) the only thing on that slide is a bar chart - there are no other Shapes.

To re-state my objective: it is to be able set the chart sheet range DYNAMICALLY. However the approach I am using by specifying a Cell Range crashes the routine with the unhelpful diagnostic of "Automation error (Error 440)"

FYI, I did also try this format:

```
Mychart.SetSourceData Source:="='Sheet1'!$A$1:$M$4"
```

Although this format is useless for changing the range dynamically, I just wanted to see what would happen.

The result was as follows:

1. When I tested it on a really old PowerPoint file created about 12 years ago, it DID successfully change the chart range. BUT, it also (i) switched the rows/ columns, and (ii) changed the colours of all the bars in the chart.
2. When I tested it on a PowerPoint file I created today, with exactly the same type of bar chart and exactly the same data, it did NOT change the chart range - but at least it didn't completely re-arrange the chart!!

Go figure.

Anyway as I said, this format is useless for changing the chart range dynamically.

Pls see the full basic routine below - any help you can provide to fix the SetSourceData problem would be appreciated!

```
Sub Demo()

Dim MySlide As Slide
Dim Mychart As Chart
Dim my_Filename As String
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim Last_num_col As Integer

'Get filename from user and open PowerPoint file
MsgBox "Browse to find your presentation. . .", , "DEMO VBA"

'Get filename from user
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "PowerPoint Files", "*.ppt, *.pptx"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = True Then my_Filename = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
    
Presentations.Open my_Filename

Set MySlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set Mychart = MySlide.Shapes(1).Chart
Mychart.Select
Mychart.ChartData.Activate
Set Myworksheet = Mychart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)

LastRow = 4
Last_num_col = 13

Mychart.SetSourceData _ 
Source:="=Myworksheet.Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(LastRow,Last_num_col))"

Mychart.ChartData.Workbook.Close

my_Filename = "Updated.pptx"
ActivePresentation.SaveAs Filename:=my_Filename
ActivePresentation.Close

End Sub
```